# Android SDK - Controlling how it names new visual components automatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

For the purpose of question:

I'm writing an Android app and I have a couple of activities, each of which has three image view components on its layouts.

When I add those ImageView components on first activity's layout, they are automatically named `imageView1`, `imageView2` and `imageView3`. 
When I add those components to another activity's layout (not by copying them from previous activity, but by dragging them from components area to layout space), they are once again automaticly named `imageView1`, `imageView2` and `imageView3`. 
The naming itself is not the problem, but the problem is that Android somehow makes references between these components from different layouts just because they use same ids. Therefore, `imageView1` from the first activity becomes linked to `imageView1` from another activity. And when I try to change some of those components, the rest of referenced components automatically applies that change too!

The question is: How can I control the way or order in which SDK automatically assigns ids to newly created components?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant control it. It is auto generated IDS. For each imageview you should have different ids. Because once you build the code and if you look at .R File you will find only 1 imageview1,imageview2,imageview3. so they reference to same IDs.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm wondering if there is a way for SDK to see into R.java and to avoid re-using the id that's already assigned to another control. Or maybe to set up some pattern for auto-naming, for example <activity-name>-<control-id>. That way, you could have two imageView1 controls in two activities, but each would have a prefix with it's activity name.

Comment: I dont think so that we can control autonaming to avoid reusing id thats already assigned in different file. But i appreciate your question.